# java: Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS Err:S1000 Exp: Before start of result set

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I used to execute this query with no problems what so ever, but lately i've been having exceptions.

(on a mysql server)

```
48442 [NioProcessor-1] ERROR c.x.xpofacebook.mysql.MysqlDb - SQLException: Before start of result set
48443 [NioProcessor-1] ERROR c.x.xpofacebook.mysql.MysqlDb - SQLState: S1000
48443 [NioProcessor-1] ERROR c.x.xpofacebook.mysql.MysqlDb - VendorError: 0
48451 [NioProcessor-1] ERROR c.x.xpofacebook.mysql.MysqlDb - stack trace: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
```

The code:

```
String createPlayerRow = "insert into highscore_challenge_player "
            + "(fb_user_id,played,best_score,highscore_challenge_id) values ((select fb_user.id from fb_user where uid=?),?,?,?)";
        stmt.close();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(createPlayerRow,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setLong(1, uid);
        stmt.setInt(2, 0);
        stmt.setInt(3, 0);
        stmt.setInt(4, highscoreChallengeId);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        rowId = rs.getInt(1); <--- ERROR IN THIS LINE
```

any ideas ? !?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [to get to the first result](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) before you can start looking at items in it.

More explicitly: you need to call `rs.next()` at least once before you can ever access results.  More generally, you need to call `next` n times to look at the n-th row, and with sql results, the count starts at 1, not 0.

Comment: @ufk: no prob - I actually learned the answer to this question here asking my own similar question.  Make sure to give back when you see it come up!